# Can I stash my items somewhere?

Tags: mass-effect-andromeda

My inventory is slowly filling up, and I'm not entirely sure about which weapons, mods or items are useful. So I don't want to just throw away all of it, but I need to regain some inventory space.

Is there a way to stash excess items somewhere?

Comment: This mechanic was not there in previous games. I really need an infinite capacity container like in Skyrim.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, there is no "stash" to store your excess items in. Best bet is to make sure you sell all trash to vendors as a habit and keep destroying unwanted items to stay within your inventory limit.

It is possible to increase your inventory capacity though, with the two Andromeda Viability Point perks "Trade Capacity" and "Trade Capacity II" under Commerce Cryo pods.

Comment: Don't forget that you can _deconstruct_ some things instead of destroying them, to get materials out of them—and especially used augments back from them so you can re-use them.

Comment: @Mufasa and how do I deconstruct?

Comment: @NVZ For items that can be deconstructed (not all can be), there is a button for it when viewing the item in your Inventory. For items that can't be destructed, then a destroy button will be shown instead—but in that case you may want to sell it instead.

Comment: @Mufasa Thanks. I remember seeing a warning message saying my inventory is full, and I chose to deconstruct​ the items as soon as I picked them up from gameplay. Didn't know I could do that in the inventory.